# How to return data from task in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, httpresponse, openweathermap

I have problem with this for so long. I'm thinking about adding this question so long, but i decided to do this. So:

How to get response in `getWeather` func? Its my first app in Swift. I'm a C# developer, Swift is a magic for me.

```
class ApiConnector{
    
    var validator = Validator();
    var  weatherMapper = WeatherMapper();


    public func ApiConnector(){}
    
    public func getWeather(city: String) -> Weather{
        let urlString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&lang=pl&units=metric&appid="+Configuration.AppTokenId;
        
        if validator.Validate(city: city) {
            let response = request(url: urlString)
            
            return weatherMapper.Map(Json: response);
        }
        return Weather();
    
    }
    
    
    private func request(url: String) -> [String: Any]{
        
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default // Session Configuration
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config) // Load configuration into Session
        let url = URL(string: url)!
        var tmp = [String: Any]();
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                
            } else {
                
                do {
                    
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
                    {
                        
                        tmp = json;
                        
                        print(tmp);
                    }
                    
                } catch {
            
                    print("error in JSONSerialization")
                    
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        
        return tmp;
        
    }
    
    }
```